# Error 13 Webhook call failed error 500: Internal server error

Tags: java, android, dialogflow-es, webhooks

I'm integrating a chatbot using dialogflow v2 API in my code but I'm not getting any response from my agent. I checked the post method on GCP and it showed the above error in fulfillment. How do I fix it or have i not set it up properly

I've checked the session name and the project i'd being set from the key and they are correct. I'm getting an error while detecting intent in my app. The queryInput and language are set properly here.

```
public class RequestJava extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, DetectIntentResponse> {
    fragment_speak fragment;
    private SessionName session;
    private SessionsClient sessionsClient;
    private QueryInput queryInput;

    RequestJava(fragment_speak fragment, SessionName session, SessionsClient sessionsClient, QueryInput queryInput) {
        this.fragment = fragment;
        this.session = session;
        this.sessionsClient = sessionsClient;
        this.queryInput = queryInput;
    }

    protected DetectIntentResponse doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        //try{
            DetectIntentRequest detectIntentRequest =
                    DetectIntentRequest.newBuilder()
                            .setSession(session.toString())
                            .setQueryInput(queryInput)
                            .build();

            Log.d("DetectIntentRequest:","Intent Is: " + detectIntentRequest );

            Log.d(" Request is "," " + sessionsClient.detectIntent(detectIntentRequest));

            return sessionsClient.detectIntent(detectIntentRequest);
        //}
        /*catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("36","In catch block");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;*/
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(DetectIntentResponse response) {
        this.fragment.callbackV2(response);
    }

}
```

This is the response i get.

```
{
  "responseId": "7dfcd725-550d-4fb1-9cd3-e5a2223eda21",
  "queryResult": {
  "queryText": "what is your age?",
  "action": "smalltalk.agent.age",
  "parameters": {
    "age": ""
  },
  "allRequiredParamsPresent": true,
  "fulfillmentText": "Isn't age just a number?",
  "fulfillmentMessages": [
    {
      "text": {
        "text": [
          "Isn't age just a number?"
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "intent": {},
  "intentDetectionConfidence": 1,
  "diagnosticInfo": {
    "webhook_latency_ms": 125
  },
  "languageCode": "en-us"
},
"webhookStatus": {
  "code": 13,
  "message": "Webhook call failed. Error: 500 Internal Server Error"
  }
}
```